# Calculating great-circle distance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, great-circle

`dist(coords)` provides the distance matrix using Euclidean distances; it also provides several other options. But it doesn't provide any option such as the haversine formula.

`distHaversine()` calculates the distance I want (great-circle) for given two set of lat/long coordinates. I am wondering if there is an existing package/function that calculates great-circle distance matrix using the haversine formulation.

Comment: have you tried `library("sos"); findFn("{great circle} distance")` (and variations)?

Comment: Do you need the haversine formula or just the matrix based distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you may already have noticed, `distHaversine()` will compute the distance between a single point and a two-column matrix of coordinates.

To compute all pairwise distances between **two** coordinate matrices, just use `apply()` to iterate row-by-row through one of the matrices, computing each of its points' distance to all of the points in the other.

```
library(geosphere)

## Example coordinates (here stored in two column matrices)
cc1 <- rbind(c(0,0),c(1,1))
cc2 <- rbind(c(90,0),c(90,90), c(45,45))

## Compute matrix of distances between points in two sets of coordinates
apply(cc1, 1, FUN=function(X) distHaversine(X, cc2))
#          [,1]    [,2]
# [1,] 10018754 9907452
# [2,] 10018754 9907435
# [3,]  6679169 6524042
```

**Interesting note:** A quick glance under the hood at `sp::spDists()` (which *does* compute pairwise distances between two matrices) reveals that it uses an essentially identical `apply()`-based strategy. The main difference, beyond some additional error checking and argument passing is that it applies the function `spDistsN1()` where we apply `distHaversine()`.

Comment: Perfect! `spDists(data, longlat=TRUE)` is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Just for the record, it doesn't immediately seem that `spDists()`' uses the Haversine formula for its "Great Circle distance (WGS84 ellipsoid)" distance computations. You'll know, though, whether that matters for your application.