# Calculate large number of permutations in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, large-data, geosphere

I have 2 large dataframes in R, both with circa 100k rows, which hold lists of geo coordinates (lat/ long). I am looking to iterate across them getting all combinations between items and thereafter, applying a function to it.

Because the number of combinations is around 11 billion (11 x 1.000.000.000), my original idea of using a loop is not applicable.

The dataframes would resemble something like:

```
A<-as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(-0.1822,-0.4419,0.2262),rbind(51.5307,51.4856,51.4535)))

(...)
<!-- -->

V1 . V2

-0.1822 . 51.5307 

-0.4419 . 51.4856

 0.2262 . 51.4535

B<- as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(-0.4764,-0.2142,-0.2197),rbind(51.5221,51.4593,51.5841))) 
(...)
<!-- -->

V1 . V2

-0.4764 . 51.5221

-0.2142 . 51.4593

-0.2197 . 51.5841
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
V1a .   V2a .   V1b .   V2b


-0.1822 . 51.5307 . -0.4764 . 51.5221  

-0.4419 . 51.4856 . -0.4764 . 51.5221

 0.2262 . 51.4535 . -0.4764 . 51.5221

-0.1822 . 51.5307 . -0.2142 . 51.4593

-0.4419 . 51.4856 . -0.2142 . 51.4593

(...)
```

Another post here in stackoverflow ([a link][Calculating great-circle distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615063/calculating-great-circle-distance-matrix) ) suggests using:

apply(A, 1, FUN=function(X) distHaversine(X, B))

However, I suspect that the matrix created is too large for it to complete the calculations.

Any ideas on how to solve this efficiently? Keeping in mind that my objective is thereafter to apply the Haversine function to calculate distances between the points.

Thanks
J

Comment: Have you tried `combn()`?

Comment: Yes I looked at it but doesn't quite do the trick. What would be your approach using it? Best regards

Comment: BTW https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geodist/index.html can help you here.

Comment: Do both data.frames contain only numbers?

Comment: Yes, these are all numeric

Comment: Very good! I’m pretty sure this can be solved in a respectable amount of time with `Rcpp` and `parallel`, which comes loaded in base R. I’ll try and code up a solution when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmb<-expand.grid(1:nrow(A),1:nrow(B))
cbind(A[cmb[,1],],B[cmb[,2],])
```

Unlike Andre's solution, this won't create combinations of the columns within each of A and B (his creates 81 rows, whereas for this sample, only 9 are desired). Not sure if this will work for your larger dataset, though.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good shout but indeed, for the larger dataset it runs out of memory: "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"

Comment: It may be your system simply cannot process such a large file. One way to address this is by doing this in several parts, and saving into a file each time. This can be achieved quite easily with my solution by looping through several break points in cmb.

Comment: Thanks, @iod, yes I am running that trial and it looks to work fine, at least for the time being. That is, it doesn't slow too much the machine.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to upvote and accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
# expand.grid(A$V1,A$V2,B$V1,B$V2)
expand.grid(cbind(A,B))
```

but as you have figured out, the result will be very huge, so I'm not sure if your code will run.

Comment: Hi, yes expand.grip was also one of the first examples I thought of. The following error appears:  "Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
  invalid 'times' value"

Comment: Do you get an error with your example data and my solution?

Comment: It works with the sample dataset, not with the live one with larger data.

Comment: @JoCosta post the result of str(df1) and str(df2)